# Show public logic if user is not authenticated React JS and Node API

Tags: node.js, authentication, reactjs, webpack

How can I show only public(i.e: home, about, authentication stuff) if the user is not signed in?

I know SPA's are not meant to refresh, but I want it to change most of the scripts on the page.

**Environment:** Using ReactJS, WebPack with an existing NodeJS API, both on separate projects.

I went through Webpack documentation and understood that it will load only the required scripts and components, but all scripts can be seen with "View Page Source". If I understood it the wrong way, please correct me.

Comment: An example: https://github.com/EcutDavid/simple-reddit/blob/master/client/components/Header.js#L16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you track if the user is logged-in or not by storing a sessiontoken somewhere in your application state tree. You can use something like Redux to manage state in your application. You first need to decide which route you need to redirect to if the user is not logged-in & requests a route which requires authentication. Lets assume you have 2 routes **/login** and **/products**. You want to ensure that only authenticated users can view the /products section. The way you accomplish this is by redirecting to /login by checking the sessiontoken value of your state which you can pass as props to your Products component mapped to the /products route.

Use something like **react-router**

In the Products component use something like below

```
class Products extends Component{
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
        let {sessiontoken}=nextProps;
        if (!sessiontoken)
           nextContext.router.push('/login');
    }
}

Products.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

In the code above we are reading the value of sessiontoken which is passed as props from a higher order Container component. In case there is no sessiontoken it will redirect to /login. As long as your APIs return an HTTP 401 on encountering an invalid sessiontoken this will work perfectly for you and you don't need to worry about people being able to view page source.

Comment: I was worried about the source code being available and that I was not taking security to a production level. Thank you!